# https://publish.twitter.com/oembed と https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json について

Tags: twitter

**GET statuses/oembed へのリクエストURLとして、2通りあり、何れでアクセスしても期待した結果を取得できるのですが、両者の違いは何ですか？**
・上の方が新しくて、下の方が古い？
・この件に関して言及しているページはどこかにないですか？(いつまでサポートするとか、そう言った情報があれば知りたいのですが…)

- `https://publish.twitter.com/oembed` についての[Twitter公式ドキュメント](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-oembed.html)
- `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json` についての[非公式翻訳ドキュメント](http://westplain.sakuraweb.com/translate/twitter/Documentation/REST-APIs/Public-API/GET-statuses-oembed.cgi)

Comment: 二つ目のリンク先は公式ドキュメントの**非公式**な勝手翻訳であり、最終更新日も明記されていないので(公式ドキュメントと比較して)信用度は劣ります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json はTwitter REST API v1であり、[2013/6/11に廃止](https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/a/2013/api-v1-retirement-final-dates.html)されています。[web.archive.orgに残るドキュメントページ](http://web.archive.org/web/20130910195245/https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/oembed)も。

Comment: リンク提示ありがとうございました。別途ご回答いただいたように、
”https://publish.twitter.com/”を使用した方が良さそうですね

Answer (score 2):

[公式ドキュメント](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-oembed.html)には https://publish.twitter.com/oembed が記載されていますし、https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json を使った場合エラーになる質問も英語版Stackoverflowで見つかりました。
(回答に対して返答がないため、URLが原因だったとははっきり言えないのですが…。)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634341/statuses-oembed-of-twitter-rest-api-v1-1-returns-errors-message-sorry-t

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json を使わねばならない理由がないのであれば https://publish.twitter.com/oembed を使うべきでしょう。